# How to use assembly to tell which kind of cpu is present

Tags: assembly, arm, x86-64, intel, amd-processor

So since I am learning assembly and difference CPU types use different features or registers differently. Is there a way to be able to code and tell the difference between ARM,Intel, or AMD processors?

I have been researching and haven't found anything.

EDIT:
The Purpose of this question was to determine that we would be creating assembly code for all platforms and if they would run based on the CPU and architecture alone rather than having to create seperate builds for each to make it easier. Although from the comments it seems you develop for each platform seperately

Comment: If you don't know the CPU, how would you know which assembly language to write this CPU-detecting code in?

Comment: Machine code only works on the architecture it was written for.  Writing e.g. x86-64 code excludes ARM processors.  However, within one architecture, there can be multiple CPU vendors.  You can some times distinguish them with special instructions.  For example, x86-64 has the `cpuid` instruction for this.

Comment: @fuz: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27033330 is 4-way polyglot machine code that detects x86 vs. ARM vs. AArch64 vs. MIPS(little endian).  See also [Is it possible to compile a binary which will run on both x86 and ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947388) and [x86-32 / x86-64 polyglot machine-code fragment that detects 64bit mode at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38063529)

Comment: @PeterCordes This is not best practise and I do not want to recommend anything like that to beginners.  They'll think that this is how things are done.

Comment: arm uses something called cpuid as well I believe but it is a series of registers used to detect the features of the core as well as what core is this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key words to look for would be "CPU detection" or "CPU identification".

For distinguishing between *architectures*, like ARM vs Intel (x86), the question is moot.  At the level of assembly, you had to pick an architecture to decide what instructions to code in the first place.  For instance, if you wanted to add two numbers, did you write `add eax, ebx` (assembling to the bytes `01 d8`), or did you write `add x0, x1, x2` (assembling to `20 00 02 8b`)?  In the former case, you're writing for x86.  In order to get to your supposed architecture detection code in the first place, you had to execute a lot of previous instructions that would only run on x86, so by the time you get there, you already know the answer.  In the latter case you're writing for ARM (ARM64).

(Technically the same sequence of bytes will do *something* on both architectures; but on the other one, it surely won't be what you want.  Usually the assembler/linker would tag your executable with the correct architecture, and if it doesn't match the machine where it's being run, the operating system will refuse  to execute it.)

For distinguishing between CPUs of the *same* architecture, you first have to decide which architecture that is, as the methods will likely be very different.  Very generally, there is usually some special instruction which returns information about the CPU.  On x86 you mainly use `cpuid`, on ARM64 there are various system registers accessed with `mrs`, and so on.  For how they work, and how to interpret the results, you have to consult the instruction set reference for that architecture.

For x86 in particular, there have been so many different x86 CPUs released over the years (between Intel, AMD, and other now-defunct competitors) that detection can be very complicated, depending how far back you want to go.  (For instance, the `cpuid` instruction hasn't always existed, so the issue distinguishing between older CPUs, say pre-2000, could fill a long article.)  Nowadays, there's the extra issue that your program may not even be running on x86 hardware, but may instead be in a VM with some other CPU that emulates x86.

For most purposes, the general question of "how do I tell which kind of CPU" is not really the right question to ask.  Rather, identify the particular CPU feature you are interested in using (e.g. AVX instructions, enhanced `rep movsb`, etc), and then ask "how do I tell whether this CPU supports it"?  Then usually there is a simple answer, e.g. "load 0x1234 into `eax`, execute CPUID, and check bit 7 of `ecx`" (made up example).  Beyond that, there's no point in writing a lot of code to tell the difference between a Brandy Lake i8-1234U at 2035 MHz or a Vodka Lake i9-9876Z at 3107 MHz; in principle you could find out which one you are running on, but as a programmer you have no actual reason to care.

Comment: "Brandy Lake i8-1234U at 2035 MHz or a Vodka Lake i9-9876Z at 3107 MHz" I take it these are made-up architectures :-)

Comment: Polyglot machine code is possible, see [Is it possible to compile a binary which will run on both x86 and ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947388) and [x86-32 / x86-64 polyglot machine-code fragment that detects 64bit mode at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38063529) .  Normally there's no need for that, of course; modern systems only load binaries with the right executable metadata.  But hand-crafted machine code *can* do something useful on multiple different architectures.

Comment: @SepRoland: Well, between Whiskey Lake, Coffee Lake, Ice Lake, and Skyylake [sic], the "lakes" have got most of a cocktail bar already, so I'm sure these are among the natural successors.  I guess you could throw in Amber (fluid) Lake, (Bombay) Sapphire Rapids, (Bacardi) Goldmont...

Comment: @PeterCordes: True.  So, readers should assume every sentence in my post carries an implicit "unless you are doing some kind of ludicrous hackery"  :-)